# select query in sqlite(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have problem while selecting data from database.
I created the "foldertable" in database with following query

```
CREATE TABLE foldertable(fid integer primary key autoincrement,foldername text);
```

and here is my code to get foldername according to fid(folderid)

```
-(NSString *)getFolderFromDatabase:(int)folderId
{
        NSString * retriveFolderName;

        UIApplication * application=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
        ScrapMemoAppDelegate * appDelegate=application.delegate;
        NSString * destinationPath=[appDelegate getDestinationPath];
        sqlite3 * database;
        int retriveWhere=folderId;

        if(sqlite3_open([destinationPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
        { 
            const char * query="select foldername from foldertable where fid = ?;";
            sqlite3_stmt * statement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
            {
                if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, retriveWhere);
                    retriveFolderName=[NSString stringWithCString:sqlite3_column_text(statement,0) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                }
                else 
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }

                sqlite3_reset(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
        return retriveFolderName;
}
```

But I get null foldername while I fired same query on terminal it gives proper name.Please 
provide me solution.

Comment: "Provide me solution." You could have asked a bit nicer.

Comment: `[ProvideMeSolution appendString:@" please"];`

Comment: Have you run this through the debugger? Does `sqlite2_open` succeed? Does `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeed? BTW - you really should use `sqlite3_open_v2`.

Comment: Yup sqlite2_open and sqlite3_prepare_v2 succeed.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code, the primary issue is that you try to execute (step) the query and then you try to bind the value for `fid`. You need to do the bind first.